# Rcurl - remove /r/n line break from getURL()

Tags: r, csv, line, break, rcurl

I have a .csv file (dim_boolean.csv) in a FTP folder with the following structure:

```
boolean_key,yes_no,open_close,boolean
1,Yes,Open,TRUE
2,No,Close,FALSE
```

I want to move this file into my local machine by using `getURL()` from the `RCurl` package. But I need it with the same structure, including the new line character being used.

This is my code:

```
file <- paste0("sftp://..../data/", "dim_boolean.csv")
content <- try(getURL(file,
               userpwd = "username:password",
               curl = getCurlHandle(ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)))
write(content, "dim_boolean.csv")
```

But the `content` variable has an additional `\r` for the line break: `"ï»¿boolean_key,yes_no,open_close,boolean,created_at\r\n1,Yes,Open,TRUE,\r\n2,No,Close,FALSE,\r\n"`.

Since I'll be working with a very large fact table soon, I don't want to touch the data again, so just replacing that character is not an option (e.g `content <- gsub("\r\n","\n", content)`).

Is is possible in curl to set the line break? or maybe there is an alternative for `write()`? My applications cannot read this .csv correctly because there is an extra row:

When opening the csv from Excel:

[image]

When trying to use COPY command in PostgreSQL:

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that b/c of the UTF-8 BOM (the `ï»¿` at the beginning there) Excel isn't translating CRLF properly (i.e. this shouldn't normally be a problem but I've seen issues with UTF-8 and Excel before). Why won't you consider a test and subsitution before your `write()` call?

Comment: You mean doing substitution of this \r character after creating the `content` variable? The problem I have is that If I have a dataset with 1 billion rows I dont want to touch each row to replace this character.